# DART: How to bind radio button value attribute

Tags: dart, dart-webui

I have an array which needs to be displayed as radio buttons so inside an `iterate` I do:

```html
    <input type="radio" name="group" value="{{val}}" ...
```

The expected out from the code below is 'Selected is 0', or 'Selected is 1' etc, but the output is always 'Selected is {{val}}'.

So the question is, how do you bind a value attribute in a radio button in Dart?

The HTML:

```html
    <div id="container">
      <template iterate="val in list">
        <input type="radio" name="group" value="{{val}}" bind-value="radioSelected" on-click="showChange()">
      </template>
      <p id="text"></p>
    </div>
```

And the Dart:

```dart
    List list = ['0','1','2'];
    String radioSelected = '0';

    void showChange() {
      query("#text").text = "Selected is $radioSelected";
```

Comment: Did you set up the Dart Web UI tools as explained here : http://www.dartlang.org/articles/dart-web-components/tools.html ?

Comment: See comment below - yes, everything is set up and working.

Comment: Are you running the code in from the `out/` directory?

Comment: I think this is a bug. I reproduced your issue, and confirmed everything does indeed work if you use static value attributes. I filed https://github.com/dart-lang/web-ui/issues/311 for tracking. Thanks for asking the question!

Comment: Good catch! I'll take a look at the bug.

Comment: Its a pleasure - any upvotes are welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set up a top level `build.dart` file. It should look something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:web_ui/component_build.dart';

void main() {
  build(new Options().arguments, ['web/<my_main_html_file>.html']);
}
```

When you `run` this file, an `out/` directory will be created for you. Run the `<my_main_html_file>.html`. The bindings should work properly and the {{ }} should not appear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Yes, everything is set up correctly and is working.  This was a small part of a system, and binding etc is all working - except when I tried the above.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think Seth is right this is a bug. In the meantime, you should be able to workaround it with something like:

```
<div id="container">
  <template iterate="val in list">
    <input type="radio" name="group" bind-checked="val == radioSelected" on-click="showChange()">
  </template>
  <p id="text"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Two way binding to an expression??